# regex not returning delimiting pattern as well

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex to return string in between `li` tags.

I am looking at following 2 types of input strings:

Case 1:

```
<li>some string with spaces and special characters
```

Case2:

```
<li>some string with spaces and special characters</li>
```

I am writing a Python script.

Regex I have is:

```
<li>(.+)[\\n|</li>]
```

Problem I am facing is in Case 2.
`re.search` is returning:

```
some string with spaces and special characters</li
```

I do not want closing `</li>` or any part of it in my return string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `[\\n|</li>]` is a character class, which means any one of the characters `\n`, `|`, `<`, etc. So it matches `(.+)` greedily and only leaves the `>` for the final part. You want `(?:\\n|</li>)` instead (a non-capturing group, instead of a character class).

`(\\n|</li>)` would also work, but would capture that part as group 2 and you have no need for it, hence the addition of `?:`.

So your regex becomes:
`<li>(.+)(?:\\n|</li>)`

Comment: Hi Grismar

Thanks for your reply.

case 2 started working but regex fails for case 1

Not sure what I am missing still?

Comment: It's likely you need to tell your regex to match end of line as well - you're currently testing for a line ending, which may either not be part of the string you're testing, or it may be ignored by your regex engine unless you tell it not to.

Comment: Don't know if this helps but for me Grismar solution worked for both cases using either `r'<li>(.+)(?:\n|</li>)` rawstring (i.e. single slash \n) or `'<li>(.+)(?:\\n|</li>)` (i.e. using \\n escape).